# find a best way to traverse oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle table. Table's DDL is (not have the primary key)

```
create table CLIENT_ACCOUNT
(
    CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2(18) default ' ' not null,
    ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(18) default ' ' not null,
    ......
)

create unique index UK_ACCOUNT
    on CLIENT_ACCOUNT (CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID)
```

Then, the data's scale is very huge, maybe 100M records. I want to traverse this whole table's data with batch.

Now, I use the table's index to batch traverse. But I have some oracle grammar problems.

```
# I want to use this SQL, but grammar error.
# try to use b-tree's index to locate start position, but not work

select * from CLIENT_ACCOUNT 
WHERE (CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID) > (1,2) 
AND ROWNUM < 1000
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID
```

Has the fastest way to batch touch table data?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data in the table?

Comment: you mean traverse the hierarchy data from top to bottom and sort the rows at the same level in a hierarchy. I can't see any of that in your data example

Comment: I want to check if the database's data is correct. In this SQL example, I forget the order segment. 

SELECT * FROM CLIENT_ACCOUNT 
WHERE (CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID) > (1,2) 
AND ROWNUM < 1000 
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID,ACCOUNT_ID

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

```
select * from CLIENT_ACCOUNT 
WHERE CLIENT_ID  > '1'
and   ACCOUNT_ID > '2' 
AND ROWNUM < 1000;
```

It would at least compile, although whether it correctly implements your business logic is a different matter. Note that I have cast your filter criteria to strings. This is because your columns have a string datatype and you are defaulting them to spaces, so there's a high probability those columns contain non-numeric values.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please **edit your question** with more details; sample input data and expected output is always helpful in these situations.

---

Your data model seems odd.

Your columns are defined as varchar2. So why is your criteria numeric?

Also, why do you default the key columns to space? It would be better to leave unpopulated values as null. (To be clear, NULL is not a good thing in an indexed column, it's just better than a space.)

Comment: Thank your reply.

This SQL DDL is my company's code project. So I can't give data records.

Yes, It's odd. Columns are varchar2 type, but store number.

I want to use the B-TREE index to fast traverse the table's data to check the record's format.


SELECT * FROM CLIENT_ACCOUNT 
WHERE (CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID) > (1,2) 
AND ROWNUM < 1000 
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID,ACCOUNT_ID


If I use [CLIENT_ID > 1 AND ACCOUNT_ID > 2],cannot traverse whole table data.And execute plan is not best.

Comment: You don't need to give the whole record. You can post a test case using just CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, which - being numbers - cannot give away any company secrets. You need to provide **more information**. Just repeating what you've already told us doesn't advance our understanding.